# Multi Vendor in Magento CE 1.7

Tags: multistore, multi-vendor

i want to set-up a gift shop that sells flower and cake in all around the country from different shops in each city.

the problem is, how can i manage multiple seller in different cities which are selling same things.

i want each seller just can add some goods under a specific part of catalogue in the shop and can view just his own goods, and his own orders in admin

for example a seller from city "A" can add goods under "A" category in the shop and can access to the orders of this category.

Comment: The question is unclear. Also did you tried to google for something like "magento multi vendor"?

Comment: unfortunately i didn't know the key "multi-vendor" to search.

Comment: flower as the things on plants or flour as in what you use to make dough?

Comment: i mean flower. Bouquet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am doing exactly this right now on Community Edition using a single website/store/store view.

I am using [Unirgy's uMarketplace](http://www.unirgy.com/products/umarketplace/magento-multi-vendor-marketplace) to do it, with the MicroSite Pro add-on.  This allows you to do what you are asking.  The module allows you to create and manage users, and give them access to their own categories.  The vendors manage all their own inventory, orders, shipping methods etc using a custom interface, but they can also use the Magento backend to manage their products, the module creates a role which only gives permissions to access Catalog-> Manage Products.

They can only manage the products which are assigned to them or they have created themselves.  This is all fine, but out of the box the Unirgy module does **not** allow each vendor to manage their own categories (they can only manage which products are assigned to which categories).

The way around this, which I fed back to them this week, is as follows;

Basically I have set up my store Categories like this;

```
Root
   --  Vendor 1
       -- v1Cat 1
       -- v1Cat 2
       -- v1Cat 3
            ---SubCat1
            ---SubCat2
       -- Cat 4
    -- Vendor 2
       -- v2Cat 1
       -- v2Cat 2
    -- Vendor 3
       -- v3Cat 1
       -- v3Cat 2
```

etc etc.  You get the drift, each vendor is assigned a category set up by admin immediately below root.  So the process is that you would set up a new category and then create the vendor.  You assign that new vendor to the new category. The Microsite add-on will have automatically assigned that vendor to the Role of 'Dropship Vendor'.  You would create a new unique role (Dropship Vendor - My New Vendor) and assign the new vendor to that instead.  You would give this role slightly different permission.  In addition to giving access to Catalogue-> Manage Products via System, you also allow access to Manage Categories.

Then I used this extension here;

[http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/17717/](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/17717/s/multi-admin-with-category-management-7650/?utm_campaign=bazaarvoice&utm_medium=Default&utm_source=RatingsAndReviews&utm_content=Default)

To assign that user role to the product category that is only for that user. Bingo, the user can login to the backend and manage their own category, add new subcategories, add their products to their categories but cannot manage anyone else's category or products.  Works great, there is one small conflict but you can use this very good extension from Maison du Logiciel to fix it (the recommended fix the module generates does work in this case) : http://www.boostmyshop.com/english/magento/magento-extension-conflict.html

So your only issue is to limit categories/vendors by city. I don't want to spoil all your fun, this is possible too as I've done it on another job. Have a think about how you could use Magento's Advanced Search, and bear in mind that the Unirgy system has a custom data section for each vendor;

[image]

Like Ben Marks has said.  This will not be cheap, quick or easy.  You will have to be creative, the Unirgy suite has Ioncubed files meaning that it's not always possible to extend things the Magento way. Also, the Unirgy documention is non-existant, but their support is excellent....treat it like Stackoverflow though.  Asking vague, non-specific unresearched questions like the one you asked here won't get you any useful answers from them!

Comment: Not cheap, but this is much cheaper than an EE license agreement, and unirgy can be trusted to write good code.

Comment: Is it not possible to use the EE edition without Licence and support?

Comment: one more thing. in every city, there may be more than a flower supplier. i mean that, is it posible to restrict user access to a subcategory like this condition?

Comment: @user1549548 - If you mean 'can I have EE free?' ...nope, that's how Magento pays their bills. 2nd question, yes. You could have multiple vendors in one city, each with their own category and selling different or the same type of product.

Comment: this  is another module which works perfectly http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/marketplace-9800.html

Answer (score 2):

Magento Enterprise Edition allows for store administrators to be associated with individual scopes.

Achieving this in Community Edition would be costly and quite involved. And for both versions, store and website scopes are factors in multiple indexes, which can lead to increased hardware  costs and complexity in planning.

Comment: so you recommend using Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another option which is what the top websites (and we) do, using an external tool for the marketplace you provide access to the suppliers in a very controlled environment via a web frontend. This provides facilities such as needing admin approval before publishing the new product, in-place image editing, access control lists for the suppliers, auto-markup pricing.

The products are then auto-synched to the Magento platform, this completely separates the marketplace from the Magento frontend, which in a professional environment provides stability and many other nice features. Upgrade friendly, ability to host the marketplace separately from the website, data duplication as a backup, less likely to be hacked as you are not running third party integrated tools, no reliance on third party extensions, and many more.

We have just been told that the consultants who developed it are releasing it as a Managed Marketplace Platform (MMP) using various underlying platforms, although it is for those who want to be in the top 5% & top 1% of their business class, so enterprise grade to compete with companies like InterFlora.

Comment: Where is the link?

Comment: You may use magento marketplace module for this feature https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Extensions/Magento-Marketplace.html modules comes with tons of addon and surely will help you to reach your marketplace goal